# Is there a way to increase the frame rate from 30 to 60 without redeploying every keyframe in timeline?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I rendered my animation in 30FPS then found it hard to match the narrative exactly.

So I like to speed up some parts and slow down others, then I need enough frames to do so.
So now I like to re-render every scene in a higher frame rate, from the original 30 FPS to 60 FPS.

But I have a lot of keyframes in every scene, so I wonder if there is any magic button that can make the keyframes know where they should be after I increase FPS to 60.

### Edit 1 day after:

What I want to know really is how to move the keyframe to its position after I increase the frame FPS to 60, then I found a simple solution, select everything in the scene and move to the timeline and scale all keyframes 2 times.

I am making a machine visualization, the scene is heavy and there are many keyframes in the timeline - something for curve animation, something for shader mixing, and of course many transformations, I am not sure if my method(SX2) can conclude every keyframe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In *Output > Frame Range > Time Stretching* you can determine a new speed for your animation, for example if you choose 50/100 (or 1/2 which would be the same) you'll have twice as many images. Make sure that you move the *End* Frame though, otherwise the calculation will stop at the current frame you've set as *End* frame:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What I want to know really is how to move the keyframe to its position after I increase the frame FPS to 60, then I found a simple solution, just scale it 2 times. I am making a machine visualization, the scene is heavy and there are many keyframes in the timeline - something for curve animation, something for shader mixing, and of course many transformations, I am not sure if my method(SX2) can conclude every keyframe.

Comment: By saying scale it 2 times I mean select all the objects in the scene and move to the timeline, again select every keyframe there and scale(Press S) 2 times.